# Disable the "refactor preview" confirmation tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few weeks ago, refactoring code using <kbd>F2</kbd> worked without any confirmation. Since a few days, however, using <kbd>F2</kbd> opens up a "Refactor preview" tab in the bottom panel.

[The refactoring will not be done until I manually check what I want to refactor, and click the checkmark at the top right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdnkD.png)

I cannot find anything online or in the vscode settings. Can this be disabled so that the refactoring automatically proceeds like it used to?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Search for rename preview in Settings and disable it.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's the `C/C++` extension's bad, try replace replace it with `clangd`.

Intergrated gdb will be lost, you can try `lldb` as a substitude:

1. Install `CodeLLDB` extension in vscode;
2. Configure cmake's default debug type to `lldb` in `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "cmake.debugConfig": {
       "type": "lldb"
   }
   ```